# Raspberry Node.js & Execute command

Tags: php, javascript, linux, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to execute a Linux command from a webpage with node.js, socket.io and (I think...) PHP. I watched [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWSpRyCDfZE&feature=g-all-u), and I'd like to do the same thing, but I don't know how.

Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to their implementation is available in the GitHub repo linked in the video - [mirceageorgescu/raspi-tank](https://github.com/mirceageorgescu/raspi-tank).

---

node.js is perfectly capable of running programs. A draft could look like the following.

**Server**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('exec', function(cmd) {
    exec(cmd, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
      // do something with the output or not
    });
  });
});
```

**Client**

```
socket.emit('exec', 'cat file.txt');
```

Information on how to start the socket on the server or connect to it from the client-side is available on [socket.io](http://socket.io/#how-to-use).